# Python Pandas - trying to get counts and percentages for all fields - Can only get one or the other

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to import some survey data, loop through all fields, and run counts and percentages. I'm struggling to get this to work for both a count and percentage of each value in a question.

For example, here's what a survey question might look like:

Q1

| ID | Response |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | White |
| 2 | Black |
| 3 | Black |

**DESIRED OUTPUT**:
Q1

```
Black 2 66.6%
White 1 33.3%
```

Below is my attempt and I know it isn't correct, but I want to show that I am trying.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_excel('imp_survey_analyze.xlsx')

for column in df.columns
    print("\n" + column)
    print(df[column].value_counts())
```

Comment: You're reading your file into `dataset`. So what is `df` holding?

Comment: Not sure I'm following... I'm importing the entire survey into my dataframe and I'm trying to run counts and percentages for each question.  As my code is right now, it's doing this, but only counts.  Thanks for your comment - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
out=df['Response'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).astype(str)+'%'
```

Finally:

```
out=pd.concat([df['Response'].value_counts(),out],axis=1)
out.columns=['count','percentage']
```

Output of `out`:

```
          count     percentage
Response        
Black       2       66.7%
White       1       33.3%
```

Comment: Shoot no luck, I'm getting a 'DataFrame object has no attribute 'value counts' error.  I tried a few other tweaks, but no luck either.

Comment: @tenebrissilentio Updated answer kindly have a look...btw its `value_counts()` not `value counts`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> pd.concat([df["Response"].value_counts(), df["Response"].value_counts(normalize=True)], axis=1, keys=["Count", "%"])
       Count         %
Black      2  0.666667
White      1  0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['ID','Response'],
['1','White'],
['2','Black'],
['3','Black']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

descriptive_df = (df.groupby(by='Response').count())

descriptive_df['percentages'] = descriptive_df["ID"] / descriptive_df["ID"].sum()

print (descriptive_df)

>>> ID  percentages
>>> Response
>>> Black      2     0.666667
>>> White      1     0.333333
```